# Unable to clone from git p4 clone

Tags: git, perforce

Unable to clone to repo : (Any help would be appreciated) I am trying to clone the repo from Perforce. I have permission to repo. Verified.

```
git p4 clone --destination=/workspaces/git/lotus/main //depot/lotus/main
    Importing from //depot/lotus/main into /workspaces/git/lotus/main
    Reinitialized existing Git repository in /workspaces/git/lotus/main/.git/
    Doing initial import of //depot/lotus/main/ from revision #head into refs/remotes/p4/master
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 3287, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 3281, in main
        if not cmd.run(args):
      File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 3155, in run
        if not P4Sync.run(self, depotPaths):
      File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 2951, in run
        self.importHeadRevision(revision)
      File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 2700, in importHeadRevision
        for info in p4CmdList(["files"] + fileArgs):
      File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 475, in p4CmdList
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: are you allowed to write into `/workspaces/git/lotus/main`?

Comment: yes I am..
bboggaramrama:/usr/local/bin/p4(master)$ ls -ltr /workspaces/git/lotus/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx  3 bboggaramrama  wheel  102 Jul 31 13:23 main

Comment: And do you have read permissions for `/depot/lotus/main` and its subdirectories and files?

Comment: Yes, I do have. Basically - I am trying to clone the repo(Perforce) to Git . So that I can work on git and submit all my changes to perforce at later point of time. 

I was able to pull the repo to perforce directory. But I am unable to clone it to git

Comment: The OS error I noticed. Did something change on your machine to cause this? It seems like the account running the script does not have access to the file.

Comment: Also, have you seen the clone issues section of the documentation? http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/git-fusion/chapter_ipm_rdw_w3.html  Also some useful tips here http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Git-P4

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 2700, in importHeadRevision
    for info in p4CmdList(["files"] + fileArgs):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-p4", line 475, in p4CmdList
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

indicate that `git-p4` is essentially doing:

```
$ p4 files <some_path>
```

but receives `Permission denied`. This might happen if you downloaded `p4` and put it in your `PATH`, but forgot to `chmod` it to make it executable.